# Does the rsync command provide a safe means of transferring data from a Windows disk image to a Linux system?

Tags: linux, windows, backup, rsync, migration

I currently have Windows 10 on my computer, and I am planning on installing Ubuntu.  Before installing Ubuntu, I am planning on creating a disk image to preserve my data.  Once Ubuntu is installed, I plan to use the rsync command to transfer my Windows data to my new operating system.  I believe the proper command would be, "rsync -r SRC DEST", where SRC is the copy of my Windows home directory on an external hard drive, and DEST is the location in my Linux system where my Windows data are to be transferred.

I was wondering whether the rsync command would provide a safe means of transferring Windows data from an external hard drive to a Linux system.  Does it matter that rsync is a Linux command which would be extracting data from directories and files created in Windows?  I do not think it should matter, but I thought I should ask.

I read that rsync automatically performs a checksum on every file it transfers.  I believe that would ensure that each copied file is identical to the original.  So, there should be no danger of data loss.  Is that correct?

I understand that Windows applications do not automatically run in Linux.  Therefore, in general, one might need to worry about not being able to use files created in Windows when migrating to Linux.  However, the only Windows-specific files I have were created in Microsoft Office.  I installed a Windows version of OpenOffice onto my computer, and I checked that I was able to open my Microsoft Office files with OpenOffice.  So, I do not think I need to worry about not being able to access my Windows data.  Additionally, I understand that Wine (which is open source) and CrossOver (which is commercial software) both are able to install and run Microsoft Office in Linux.  In a worst-case scenario, I could create a dual-boot system, reinstalling Windows from my disk image.

My only concern is whether rsync might have a problem transferring Windows data to Linux.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Windows and Linux use different line endings which may mess up any text files.

Comment: "Safe" against what? Also what do you mean by "disk image"? That term has a particular meaning, but I think it may not be what you mean by it.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for the information about the line endings.  Is there any way to deal with this issue, other than creating a dual-boot system or a virtual machine?

Comment: @gronostaj I mean safe against data loss or other complications which would prevent me from accessing files or directories. I created a disk image on an external hard drive, using a wizard. According to the wizard, the image is supposed to be an exact copy of everything on my computer.

Comment: I think the question of line endings is irrelevant. Rsync is a binary protocol and wont change line endings.  This might be an issue if you edit file on Linux, but thats unrelated to rsync.

Comment: @DavidPostill I only wish to transfer personal files from a Windows system to a Linux system. I do not care about transferring software or settings. Is the issue with line endings the only potential problem? Other users seem to think line endings would not be a problem at all. I created Windows text files with Notepad, and saved the files with the .txt extension. Do you still think there would be a problem with line endings?